# Escape backslash in XML and split as separate xml node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am looking for some help to convert the following format XML using XSLT to the desired output -

Input XML:

```
 <properties>
    <entry>
        <key>first_node</key>
        <value>GDP</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>parent_node/second_node/third_node</key>
        <value>INR</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>fourth_node</key>
        <value>
            <genericData>
                <identifier>fourth_node</identifier>
                <properties>
                    <entry>
                        <key>fifth_node/sixth_node</key>
                        <value>USD</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>seventh_node</key>
                        <value>EUR</value>
                    </entry>
                </properties>

            </genericData>
        </value>
    </entry>

    <entry>
        <key>eigth_node</key>
        <value>
            <genericData>
                <identifier>eigth_node</identifier>
                <properties>
                    <entry>
                        <key>ninth_node</key>
                        <value>SGD</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>tenth_node</key>
                        <value>PSO</value>
                    </entry>
                </properties>

            </genericData>
        </value>
    </entry>

</properties>
```

Desired Output:

```
<properties>
<first_node>GDP</first_node>                          
<parent_node>
<second_node>
<third_node>INR</third_node>
</second_node>
</parent_node>                    
<fourth_node>
<fifth_node>
<sixth_node>USD</sixth_node>
</fifth_node>
<seventh_node>EUR</seventh_node>
</fourth_node>            
<eight_node>
<ninth_node>SGD</ninth_node>
<tenth_node>PSO</tenth_node>
</eight_node>     
</properties>
```

I have modified the question with a possible input XML where the format is changed a bit.

Kindly help with the XSLT Version 1 to get the desired output.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please tell us which XSLT version you use, which XSLT processor you use.

Comment: Your question mentions escaping backslashes. I don't see any backslashes, or any need to escape anything.

Comment: Thank you. I am using XSL function which is embedded in a tool. What ic an see is the XSLT stylesheet version is 1. Hope this helps.

Comment: On the slashes, I want the transformation of first "String" in <entry> tag to be converted as an element. If "/" is encountered then that should get translated to another node as shown in "Desired Output".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2 or 3 you can use the XPath `tokenize` function to construct a sequence of strings with the element names in a recursive template constructing the nested elements as needed:

```
  <xsl:template match="entry">
      <xsl:param name="element-names" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(string[1], '/')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="element-name" as="xs:string?" select="head($element-names)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$element-name">
              <xsl:element name="{$element-name}">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                      <xsl:with-param name="element-names" select="tail($element-names)"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="string[2]"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Full XSLT 3 stylesheet would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
      <xsl:param name="element-names" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(string[1], '/')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="element-name" as="xs:string?" select="head($element-names)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$element-name">
              <xsl:element name="{$element-name}">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                      <xsl:with-param name="element-names" select="tail($element-names)"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="string[2]"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtK, for XSLT 2 you would need to spell out the identity transformation and I think instead of using `head($element-names)` you would need to use `element-names[1]` and instead of the `tail` call on that variable you would need `$element-names[position() gt 1]`.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. This works perfectly well for version 3. However, I am using version 1 and i get the following error -  Can not resolve namespace prefix: #all"  and when i remove that namespace and try, i get another error - "Could not find function: tokenize
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: tokenize"

Comment: Could you please help with verison 1 ?

Comment: Find out which XSLT 1 processor you use and whether it supports http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html or similar.

Comment: Seems like tokenize is not supported. Any alternative way Martin? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor you use? They don't support the XPath 2.0 tokenize but often might support another one, for instance Apache Xalan has http://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/lib/ExsltStrings.html#tokenize(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 1.0, if you can't use any extension functions, you can achieve it by using a recursive named template to split up the path

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
  <xsl:call-template name="splitter">
    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="key" />
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="value" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="splitter">
  <xsl:param name="path" />
  <xsl:param name="value" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($path, '/')">
      <xsl:element name="{substring-before($path, '/')}">
        <xsl:call-template name="splitter">
          <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-after($path, '/')" />
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="{$path}">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test=".//entry">
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//entry" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMX

Comment: Just one word - "SUPERB". Thanks a ton. Thank you Tim.

Comment: Hello Tim. Thanks for your help earlier. However, I got to know that the <entry? tag can be different as well as illustrated in the Input XML above. The previous XSLT is not working. However, I tried to use XSLT Copy function but could only work with that in isolation dealing with only one kind of <entry> tag. How to give logic in XSLT such that it is valid for both kinds of <entry> tag formats ?

Comment: I have amended my answer, but please bear in mind in the future you should avoid making significant changes to a question after it has been answered. You should really have asked a whole new question (which could have referenced this original question for context). Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Tim. I am new to this board and didn't know the best practices. I will bear that in mind. Thanks for letting me know. Thanks again for your help. Regards.

Comment: Hi Tim, I posted a different question "Please refer to question “ Escape backslash in XML and split as separate xml node using XSLT”. I used the code here to transform the XML which is os same structure of the above XML. However, i observe that, though the XML is getting converted to the desired output, it is also printing the child elements as standalone. I.e. the elements are repeated. something like this - </main><a><b>123</b></a><b>123</b></main>. Here, element <b> is printed again as standalone.

Comment: Here is the new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740852/please-refer-to-question-escape-backslash-in-xml-and-split-as-separate-xml-nod

Comment: Hi Tim, could you please help me out with the question posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740852/please-refer-to-question-escape-backslash-in-xml-and-split-as-separate-xml-nod please?