# Please refer to question " Escape backslash in XML and split as separate xml node using XSLT"

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to convert the following XML to desired output-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <properties>
    <entry>
        <key>first_node/P_NODE</key>
        <value>
            <genericData>
                <identifier>first_node/P_NODE</identifier>
                <properties>
                    <entry>
                        <key>second_node</key>
                        <value>2</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>third_node/fourth_node/fifth_node</key>
                        <value>345</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>sixth_node/seventh_node</key>
                        <value>67</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>eigth_node</key>
                        <value>8</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>ninth_node</key>
                        <value>
                            <genericData>
                                <identifier>ninth_node</identifier>
                                <properties>
                                    <entry>
                                        <key>tenth_node</key>
                                        <value>10</value>
                                    </entry>
                                    <entry>
                                        <key>eleventh_node/twelveth_node</key>
                                        <value>1112</value>
                                    </entry>
                                </properties>
                            </genericData>


                            <genericData>
                                <identifier>ninth_node</identifier>
                                <properties>
                                    <entry>
                                        <key>x_node</key>
                                        <value>10</value>
                                    </entry>
                                    <entry>
                                        <key>y_node</key>
                                        <value>1112</value>
                                    </entry>
                                </properties>
                            </genericData>


                        </value>
                    </entry>
                </properties>
            </genericData>
        </value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>tirteenth_node</key>
        <value>
            <genericData>
                <identifier>tirteenth_node</identifier>
                <properties>
                    <entry>
                        <key>fourteenth_node</key>
                        <value>14</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>fifteenth_node/sixteenth_node</key>
                        <value>1516</value>
                    </entry>
                </properties>
            </genericData>
        </value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>seventeeth_node/eighteenth_node</key>
        <value>1718</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>nineteenth_node/twenth_node</key>
        <value>1920</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>twentyfirst_node</key>
        <value>21</value>
    </entry>
</properties>
```

Desired Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <properties>
        <first_node>
          <P_NODE>
             <second_node>2</second_node>
             <third_node>
                <fourth_node>
                   <fifth_node>345</fifth_node>
                </fourth_node>
             </third_node>
             <sixth_node>
                <seventh_node>67</seventh_node>
             </sixth_node>
             <eigth_node>8</eigth_node>
             <ninth_node>
                <tenth_node>10</tenth_node>
                <eleventh_node>
                   <twelveth_node>1112</twelveth_node>
                </eleventh_node>
             </ninth_node>
             <ninth_node>
                <x_node>10</x_node>
                <y_node>1112</y_node>
             </ninth_node>
          </P_NODE>
       </first_node>
        <tirteenth_node>
          <fourteenth_node>14</fourteenth_node>
          <fifteenth_node>
             <sixteenth_node>1516</sixteenth_node>
          </fifteenth_node>
       </tirteenth_node>
        <seventeeth_node>
          <eighteenth_node>1718</eighteenth_node>
       </seventeeth_node>
        <nineteenth_node>
          <twenth_node>1920</twenth_node>
       </nineteenth_node>
        <twentyfirst_node>21</twentyfirst_node>
    </properties>
```

Kindly let me know the XSLT which can be used to achieve the above.

I have used the code which is answered through the question "[Escape backslash in XML and split as separate xml node using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549138/escape-backslash-in-xml-and-split-as-separate-xml-node-using-xslt)". However, when I use the same code for the above XML, it is printing the child elements inside parent but also printing as standalone elements. Note: The question has been amended to represent the actual problem statement.

Thank you.

Comment: Here, the tenth node is getting repeated. "<tenth_node>10</tenth_node>" It is appearing in 9th node as it should, but also getting repeated as standalone element.

Comment: The XSLT i am using is in  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549138/escape-backslash-in-xml-and-split-as-separate-xml-node-using-xslt

Comment: You should really edit the question to include the XSLT you are using. Thank you

Comment: You are still referring to slashes as backslashes, which is terribly confusing.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I updated the question to represent the actual and exact problem statement. Regards.

Comment: Why is your title "please refer to question"? What's that trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You firstly need to add a second template matching `entry` nodes which has `genericData` under it, as you will need to repeat the code for each such node

```
<xsl:template match="entry[value/genericData]">
  <xsl:for-each select="value/genericData">
    <xsl:call-template name="splitter">
      <xsl:with-param name="path" select="identifier" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

You also need to tweak the code that checks for descendant `entry` nodes, so that it only gets the first level of `entry` nodes, not all descendants

```
 <xsl:when test="self::genericData">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="properties/entry" />
 </xsl:when>
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
  <xsl:call-template name="splitter">
    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="key" />
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="value" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry[value/genericData]">
  <xsl:for-each select="value/genericData">
    <xsl:call-template name="splitter">
      <xsl:with-param name="path" select="identifier" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="splitter">
  <xsl:param name="path" />
  <xsl:param name="value" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($path, '/')">
      <xsl:element name="{substring-before($path, '/')}">
        <xsl:call-template name="splitter">
          <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-after($path, '/')" />
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="{$path}">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::genericData">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="properties/entry" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a ton. I see what you are saying. Yes, there are nested "Entries" in my XML. But, I see the child elements are getting merged here.Say, if the <genericData> node is getting repeated within the <ninth_node> with identifier same as <ninth_node> with its own child elements, after translation, all the child elements are coming inside one <ninth_node>, rather i wanted <ninth_node><child_elements1></ninth_node><ninth_node>child_elements2</ninth_node>.But what i am getting is <ninth_node> <child_elements1><child_elements2></ninth_node>.The child elements are getting merged into one node

Comment: See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiK2. The XSLT does produce the desired output you have shown in your question.

Comment: Thank you Tim. You are right. However, if the "GenericData" is repeated, the children are getting merged.

Comment: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiK2/5   here i have edited the ninth node to include another generic data tag with same identifier name which is "ninth_node"., i am seeing that both x_node and y_node are merged with first "generic data" child elements inside one ninth node

Comment: I need      <ninth_node>
            <tenth_node>10</tenth_node>
            <eleventh_node>
               <twelveth_node>1112</twelveth_node>
            </eleventh_node>
</ninth_node>
<ninth_node>
            <x_node>10</x_node>
            <y_node>1112</y_node>
</ninth_node>

Comment: You really need to make sure the XML in your question accurately represents the XML you are actually using. You should edit your question to show this XML, and the output you expect (although I will have to delete my answer in this case, as it will no longer be relevant). Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Tim. Let me update my question with this change and also title of the question by removing the word backslashes as suggested by Martin.

Comment: I've re-instated my answer with some new, improved XSLT that copes with multiple `genericData` elements.

Comment: Awesome Tim. You are my GURU in XSLT. I am very new to this topic. The way you explained the logic to derive at a solution is making me feel comfortable with this topic. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Tim, Would you like to help me out with an answer for  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762727/merge-xml-nodes-sharing-the-same-name-with-list-in-the-node-name-and-also-at  Warm Regards.